# Vaadin visual editor in IntelliJ IDEA can't run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vaadin

Could you help me
How in IDEA can I run vaadin visual editor?

I try:
 - new -> vaadin custom component

I can't find how to run visual editor(

Answer (score 1):

The visual editor is currently only supported in Eclipse as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

## Update – *Vaadin Designer* works in IntelliJ

The [Vaadin Designer](https://vaadin.com/designer) visual layout editing tool works in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA Community/Ultimate version 14 and later.

*Vaadin Designer* requires a commercial license.

### Designer supported in IntelliJ & Eclipse, but *not* NetBeans

[Vaadin Designer](https://vaadin.com/designer) requires either [IntelliJ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) or [Eclipse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#). Not supported in [NetBeans](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) nor any other [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDE).

Per [*Release Notes*](https://vaadin.com/designer/release-notes) as of 2017-03.

#### Vaadin Designer 2

Designer 2.0.0 is for Vaadin 8.

Requires:

- Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)+, Java EE edition. Eclipse Neon 4.6 recommended
- JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 14+ Community/Ultimate

#### Vaadin Designer 1

Designer 1.2.1 is for Vaadin 7.

Requires:

- Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)+, Java EE edition
- JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 14+ Community/Ultimate